# how to convert directstream from kafka into data frames in spark 1.3.0

Tags: apache-spark, hive, streaming, apache-kafka

After creating a direct stream like below:

```
val events = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
  ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
```

I would like to convert the above stream into data frames, so that I could run hive queries over it. Could anyone please explain how this can be achieved? I am using spark version 1.3.0

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [Spark Streaming programming guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#dataframe-and-sql-operations), try this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
object SQLContextSingleton {
  @transient private var instance: SQLContext = null

  // Instantiate SQLContext on demand
  def getInstance(sparkContext: SparkContext): SQLContext = synchronized {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new SQLContext(sparkContext)
    }
    instance
  }
}
case class Row(key: String, value: String)
eventss.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  val sqlContext = SQLContextSingleton.getInstance(rdd.sparkContext)
  import sqlContext.implicits._
  val dataFrame = rdd.map {case (key, value) => Row(key, value)}.toDF()
  dataFrame.show()
}
```